# Weka setOutputFormat(outFormat) results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, weka

I am writing a filter in weka based on the documentation in the manual. Since the filter I will implement needs to see the whole dataset first, I based myself on the SimpleBatchFilter.

In the manual of weka there are some example (3 to be exactly) that are Batch-based filters. I have tried all three of them, yet I always get `NullPointerException` when calling the method `setOutputFormat(outFormat)`.

Can someone explain?

**Edit**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at weka.filters.Filter.setOutputFormat(Filter.java:234)
at development.core.filters.LatentDirichletAllocationFilter.batchFinished(LatentDirichletAllocationFilter.java:227)
at weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(Filter.java:682)
at development.core.representation.LatentDirichletAllocation.performOn(LatentDirichletAllocation.java:42)
at test.main(test.java:34)
```

Comment: put the stacktrace in problem

Comment: @lakshman I added the stacktrace

Comment: in that method there is no reason to throw null pointer exception. you can attach the weka source to debugger to find the line that exception happen